# Watson Studio using ibmdbr in Rstudio to connect to DB2 Z/OS

Tags: data-science-experience, watson-studio

I'm trying to use RStudio to connect to the DB2 for Z/OS backend using ibmdbr odbcDriverConnect and getting error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con.text) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER' : file not found
2: In odbcDriverConnect(con.text) : ODBC connection failed
```

My code is: 
(added the package/library used)

```
install.packages("ibmdbR")
library(ibmdbR) 
driver.name <- "{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}"
...
con.text <- paste("DRIVER=",driver.name,
                  ";Database=",db.name,
                  ";Hostname=",host.name,
                  ";Port=",port,
                  ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP",
                  ";UID=", user.name,
                  ";PWD=",pwd,sep="")
con <- odbcDriverConnect(con.text)
```

`IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER` is what I use in my local R.   I can't seem to find what driver to specify for the IBM Watson Desktop (on cloud)  Anyone have a recommendation as to what the cloud server installed for the DB2 for Z/OS driver name?

Comment: Check the contents of `/etc/odbcinst.ini` for a list of installed drivers.

Comment: I'm using Watson Desktop on IBM Cloud.  no access to environment.

Answer (score 0):

Is JDBC an option? Please take a look at https://medium.com/ibm-data-science-experience/using-dashdb-with-rstudio-in-data-science-experience-dad78ea044ba

Comment: This example uses ibmdbR, which I'm using (not shown in my example above)  and it needs a dsn_driver .. which is configured in /etc/odbcinst.ini or /etc/inst.ini file, which I don't have access to.   The issue here is what  ODBC driver is installed/available to rstudio in Watson Desktop on IBM Cloud and I need the one with the ZOS license.  Which I assume they have one installed since you can specify a Connection using DB2 for Z/OS.

Comment: JDBC is an option.  but not with ibmdbR.  Unless someone else can come up with an example, I couldn't get ibmdbR to work with a jcc driver.   What I did find is this example.. using RJDBC with dependencies rJava & DBI 
I found the following as my base example for setup: https://medium.com/ibm-data-science-experience/connecting-dsx-rstudio-to-on-prem-db2-for-z-os-database-8354c9a8dc55